# Rave report text justification while generating the document dynamically (from code)

Tags: delphi, code-generation, rave-reports

We generate a document using ravereports, Delphi.
I have to print a paragraph in which some specific words should be bold.

If I use a datamemo component I can't handle bold issue.
Therefore I generate the document dynamically by setting font properties. This resolves the bold-font issue, but a new issue is raised: text-justification.

Sample text:

You are required to submit all your **Original Academic Certificates on the date of
 
   Joining** and would be held with the company till the completion of your service
   agreement.

The above paragraph has 3 lines of text in my system, in that report lines 1 and 2 end in different places.but we need

1. Two lines must end with same position
2. **Original Academic Certificates on the date of Joining** must be in bold.

     **Note :** we have number of such paragraphs,some of them are dynamic.

How can we do it? please suggest solution.

Comment: Your issue is not text-justification, it is word-wrap or font-size. are you using the same fonts for screen and print?

Comment: hi please see the updated question , and give me your suggesion.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply,
      Actually i need to print 3 pages of data ,
      for that i designed a .rav file for format.

```
  in that
```

**alternative-1** : i took the dataMemo (for multiple lines).
       In some paragraphs some text should be bold , i can't handle it.(Paragraph text is not static as per the length/Data), 
    we work-out for some text bold and some text plain, but i couldn't get solution for it.

Then i tried **alternative-2**

**alternative-2**
      We dynamically writing text into canvas to print the text with required font. to cut the word at the end we follow the some logic. but finally we are not able to justify right-side.

So, Finally provide solution any how,
    Alternative-1 or 
    Alternative-2.

Thanks.